# Can we use semicolon independently at the beginning of a for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

What is the meaning of this type of syntax in the for-loop?

```java
public class ReverseNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 1234567, reversed = 0;

        for (; num != 0; num /= 10) { // <-- meaning of the first ; ?
            int digit = num % 10;
            
            reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;
        }

        System.out.println("Reversed Number: " + reversed);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(;num != 0; num /= 10) {` this means the initializer (usually int i = 0 or num = 1234567 in your case) is declared outside of the loop. So the initializer part of the loop can be left empty.

Comment: Since `num` is initialized before the loop, so initializing it again in the initialization part of the `for` loop has been skipped and is completely valid thing to do. You could also skip conditional part of the loop to define an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` statement is composed of 3 parts `for(statement A; statement B; statement C)`:

- **Statement A** is the initializer statement. It is executed only one time. Usually, you create your variables you want to use in the for loop
- **Statement B** is the stop condition. It is executed every time at the beginning of the for loop, to determine if you should do the for loop one more time
- **Statement C** is the operation to execute every time at the end of the for loop (like incrementing your variable for instance).

All of them are optional.
Here some examples of for loop:

```
for(;;) {
    // infinite loop
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Loop 10 times and increment i each time
}
int b = i; // impossible. i does not exist anymore
// this for is equivalent to :
int i = 0;

for(; i < 10; i++) {
    // Almost the same. The difference here is that I can be accessed after the for loop
}
int b = i; // possible, because i is still visible. 

for(int a = 0;; a++) {
    // Infinite loop (because no stop condition) to increment variable a
    System.out.println(a);
}
for(int constant = 0;;) {
    // Infinite loop (no stop condition) and you can use constant variable (but will always be 0)
    System.out.println(constant);
}
```

Comment: What if i remove int i=0; before for(; i<10;i++)? Now what will be the initial condition>

Comment: if you remove int i=0 then your code won't compile anymore... because "i" will not be known anymore.

Comment: then what if i remove value of i? only write int i.

Comment: Then i will be 0, as it is the default value for a non-initialized int variable

Comment: @RUAROThibault No, you'll get a compiler error saying "`i` may not have been initialized". Only fields have default values.

Comment: @HarryPotter The variables used in the `for` loop are subject to the same rules as all variables. They must be declared—and in the case of local variables, initialized—before they can be used.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ; in the beginning  of the loop that means , you don't have already initialized its value
in the below exapmle:

```
int num = 1234567, reversed = 0;
for(;num != 0; num /= 10) {
int digit = num % 10;
reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;
}
```

it is already picking the value of "num"

In case if you comment the num value you will get an error.

Comment: num!=0 is showing condition here but num/=10 what is showing this?

Comment: This is assignment operator a/=b it is similar to a=a/b